# OAuth2 password grant complaining about response_type

Tags: django, oauth

I'm trying to get an access token from an OAuth2 provider based on [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit) through a client registered with the [Resource Owner Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3).

According to the [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2), the `response_type` parameter is not needed in this type of grant but I'm still getting an error message asking for it whenever I POST to the authorization endpoint:

```
error=invalid_request&error_description=Missing+response_type+parameter.
```

Needless to say that `grant_type="password"`, `username` and `password` are provided in the request and that `client_id`/`client_secret` are used to authenticate the client with Basic authentication (since the client is "confidential").

Any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not POST a grant to the *authorization* endpoint, but to the *token* endpoint.